# Tropical geometry: practical applications?

Tags: applications, data-analysis, tropical-geometry

In 1960, E. Wigner published a paper entitled "[The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences)". Theoretical mathematical structures pave the way to further advances and empirical predictions in applied sciences. Recently, for instance, applications of topology were discussed in [Why does topology rarely come up outside of topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592421/why-does-topology-rarely-come-up-outside-of-topology/1592463#1592463), in the domain of data science, or data analysis/mining.

[image: Tropical geometry]

I recently read basic papers on [tropical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry) ([above  picture origin](https://u.osu.edu/kennedy.28/2014/07/23/reading-list-for-tropical-geometry-and-spherical-varieties/)); [max-plus algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-plus_algebra) bears similarities with image processing with mathematical morphology, but I have not seen clear connections yey.  Are there interesting potential applications of this field in applied domains?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234051/applications-of-algebraic-geometry-to-machine-learning

Comment: An interesting application
http://www.esrc.ac.uk/news-events-and-publications/impact-case-studies/economist-helps-bank-of-england-deal-with-financial-crisis/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Algebraic Statistics for Computational Biology* by Lior Pachter and Bernd Sturmfels, published by Cambridge University Press in 2005, applies tropical geometry to philogenetic trees.

Comment: You win by resistance to fierce competition :)